# Android location app crashing after add Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to create location marker on Google map using Android studio and getting location from Firebase realtime database.
After I add Firebase realtime database to my app it's keep crashing. Please help.
here is MapsActivity.JAVA code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


String latitude,longitude,value;
int n,n1;
float x,y;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("device");

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

            n = value.indexOf("attitude=0");

            latitude = value.substring(n+10,n+17);
            longitude  =  value.substring(n+28,n1+34);

            x = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
            y = Float.parseFloat(longitude);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
};

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
   // x = (float) 13.9365;
   // y = (float) 100.4991;

    x = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
     y = Float.parseFloat(longitude);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(x, y);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Device1"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));



}}
```

And here is what's seem to be problem

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smart, PID: 13831
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at com.example.smartbin.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:98)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
    at cx.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817068@20.18.17 (100700-0):2)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817068@20.18.17 (100700-0):2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Path is a unique key I don't know how to create path so I try substring and turn it into float. 
Thank you

Comment: At which particular line of code does that error occur?

Comment: The code shows no error. So I’m not sure.

Comment: This is an error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference`. At which particular line of code does this error occur?

Comment: I guess this one . x = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
  y = Float.parseFloat(longitude);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `x = Float.parseFloat(latitude)` crashes, because the latitude is null. You init the value of latitude on this line `latitude = value.substring(n+10,n+17);`, This will only run when there is child add to the FirebaseDatabase, so when the `onMapReady` is called, there is no child to add to database, so the latitude is null.

Comment: What should I do instead of it

Comment: You can move the code : x = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
y = Float.parseFloat(longitude);

// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(x, y);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Device1"));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney)); to the onChildAdded method.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Now it shows map for a while but still crashing.